# Unity2D - Randomly instantiated objects need to not spawn close to each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner to Unity. I'm creating an educational snake game that randomly spawns three potential answers. It's working, however I need to not have them spawn close to each other. I also need not to have any of them spawn near the player/snake. Someone already tried to help me and I asked him for help, but it seems like he's unable to fix the problem and the objects still spawn near each other.

```
void GeneratePotentialAnswers()
{
    allAnswers.Clear();
    List<Vector3> AnswerPositions = new List<Vector3>();
    AnswerPositions.Add(player.transform.position);
    for (int i = 0; i < potentialAnswers.Count; i++)
    {
        GameObject ans = Instantiate(enemyAnswerPrefab);

        Vector3 pos;
        int index = 0;
        bool tooClose = false;
        do
        {
            float rndWidth = Random.Range(15f, Screen.width - 25f);
            float rndHeight = Random.Range(15f, Screen.height - 105f);
            pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(rndWidth, rndHeight, 0f));
            pos.z = -1f;
            foreach (Vector3 p in AnswerPositions)
            {
                float distance = (pos - p).sqrMagnitude;
                if (distance < 3f)
                {
                    tooClose = true;
                }
            }
            index++;
        }

        while (tooClose == true && index < 500);
        Debug.Log(index);

        AnswerPositions.Add(pos);

        ans.transform.localPosition = pos;
        ans.GetComponent<Answer>().potentialAnswer = potentialAnswers[i];
        ans.GetComponent<Answer>().addToScore = scorePerCorrectAnswer;
        ans.GetComponent<Answer>().SetAnswer();
        allAnswers.Add(ans.GetComponent<Answer>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to illustrate what you and this other person have done so far to investigate your issue. What line in the code do you think cause the issue? What is that random `while` loop doing? (It looks like an infinite loop.) If you are instantiating all the objects with the same parameters, expect similar behavior. Where is the logic for determining location? As it stands, this looks like a "fix this for me" question, versus a "here is an error I don't understand" question.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 I'm an absolute beginner and I don't really know what I'm doing. Sorry for this, this project is way too hard for me but I need to be able to complete it. Again, I'm very sorry. I'm just left alone and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Maybe try to generate coordinates on a *grid* rather than over a continuous range?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

1. Manually place GameObjects that act as spawnpoints, attach a SpawnPoint script to each of them.
2. When placing an answer, have the SpawnPoint script of the chosen spawnpoint use a SphereCastAll to check if the nearby area is free, if it is not, another spawnpoint should be selected until a free one is found.
3. When a free spawnpoint is found, instantiate the answer at its location.

**Elaboration**

A simple solution would be to have a SpawnPoint script. Which would be a script put on a set of individual spawnpoints you place manually, there could be perhaps 20 of them at various points in the map.

The SpawnPoint script could then use the SphereCastAll method, which gathers a collection of colliders in a zone of a given size, in the shape of a sphere. (Should work in 3d but maybe not 2d, find another cast type than SphereCastAll in that case).

Here is documentation on how to make a SphereCastAll, notice that you can set the radius of the spherecast.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCastAll.html

If any objects are struck by the SphereCastAll, they will be stored in the RaycastHit[] it returns. You can search through this, each RaycastHit will have a reference to the collider it hit, along with the GameObject of that collider. Meaning that you have a list of all objects within a zone.

You can then check these objects to see if they are the player or another answer.

Here is documentation for a RaycastHit.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html

Note that to gain access to the spawnpoints it would be useful to have a list of them or a manager script of sorts that can select one for you.